# Which Geometry book is more rigorous/harder?

Tags: geometry

Can anyone please tell me if the AOPS (Art of Problem Solving) Geometry is more rigorous/difficult generally than a book called "Geometry for Enjoyment and Challenge" by authors Rhoad, Milauskas and Whipple

Comment: Rigorous does not equal hard. There are university-level textbooks on arithmetic which are rigorous, but the subject material is not hard.

Comment: AOPS is more comprehensive and mechanical - they don't provide the proofs. The other book is more rigorous as it is proof oriented.

Answer (score 3):

AOPS is more comprehensive and mechanical - they don't provide the proofs. The other book is more rigorous as it is proof oriented